# Dashdb round issue

Tags: db2, rounding, db2-luw, dashdb

We are executing the below query to get some aggregated data, the issue is for some of the rows the rounding is fine bit for some the rounding doesn’t work and shows 10 digits after decimal. The selected columns have `integer` as their datatype and the data is correct, please help us to trouble shoot the issue.

```
Select
round( 
 DOUBLE(sum(IDEAL_CYCLE_TIME)) * DOUBLE(sum(PARTS_PRODUCED_COUNT)) 
 / DOUBLE(sum(RUNNING_TIME_COUNT))*100,
 2)  as value  
From PERFORMANCE_AGGR_MONTH_FACT 
Where ORG_DIM='O1' AND MONTH_NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the behavior is a result of your choice to cast the numbers to data type [DOUBLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008469.html), which is an approximation of a real number. The built-in ROUND function might therefore return an "unexpected" result like you seem to observe. For example

```
SELECT ROUND((DOUBLE(1) * DOUBLE(1)) / DOUBLE(1)*100, 2) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

returns in my environment `100.00000000000001`.

Could you use data type DECIMAL instead?